# Set global variable from within function using function parameter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, naming

How can I set a global variable from inside a JavaScript function, using the function's parameter to name the global variable itself? For example:

```
function loadLog(id){
    window.id = "test";
}
```

So if the function was called like this...

```
loadLog('apple');
```

...then the global variable created by it would have the name "apple" with the value of "test."

I have no idea what to do and how to accomplish this. I've tried searching, but came across nothing.

Comment: Bracket notation. `window[id]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elaborate on elclanrs answer, when accessing the key of an object. The keys are always strings. Id is a variable not a string.

Bracket notation works such that you need to put the quotes into the bracket when accessing the key. If not, it will look for a variable with the same name. Dot notation actually converts to bracket notation, and it looks like this,

```
time.id --> time["id"]
```

Therefore you cannot use variables with dot notation because it will surround the variable in quotes.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use square bracket notation to access the properties of an object dynamically.

```
function loadLog (id) {
    window[id] = "test";
}
```